# (Excel) Pick formula criteria/logical etc from another cell(reference)

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-formula, user-defined-functions

Im writing an If+Or function and would like to use several cell references for the different Logicals in the function, instead of writing each logical statements in the original if+or function. Any ideas of how to solve this? Hope im not too unclear here..

As example: instead of writing =If(or(A1=A2,A3=A4),A1,0) I would like to write out all different logical values in a list of cells, and the just write the original if+or formula like this: =IF(OR(B1),A1,0) where B1 contains the text "A1=A2,A3=A4"

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: B1 just has text, not a formula, and even if it had a formula it would need to include the `OR()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the INDIRECT function.

For example, if the value in cell A6 is 10, INDIRECT("A6") = 10.
So basically you can write INDIRECT("A6")=INDIRECT("A7") instead of the A1=A2 condition in your IF formula.
If you want to have "A1=A2" in one cell, you can use LEFT and RIGHT.

Here is an example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/157tRicA55TFKKOi86yYBQScnjaQE6fYxaCHFdZx4uUM/edit?usp=sharing

PS: this solution is for Google Sheets so the solution might differ a little if you're using Excel but that should work for Excel too.

Answer (score 0):

## You CANNOT Have It All

Instead of using `=IF(OR(B1),A1,0)` you have to use

e.g. `=IFOR(B1,A1)` (I prefer **""** instead of **0**, sorry)
or `=IFOR(B1,A1,0)` if you (prefer **0** instead of **""**),
or change the **ElseValue** in the declaration to **0**,
then you can use `=IFOR(B1,A1)` to get **0**.

```
Function IFOR(IfOrCell As Range, ThenCell As Range, _
    Optional ElseValue As Variant = "", _
    Optional SplitDelimiter As String = ",") As Variant
'Description:
  'Pending...

  'Recalculation
  Application.Volatile

  'Variables
  Dim arrIfOr As Variant
  Dim iIfOr As Integer
  Dim blnIfOr As Boolean

  'The Array: The Split
  If InStr(IfOrCell.Value2, SplitDelimiter) = 0 Then Exit Function
  arrIfOr = Split(IfOrCell.Value2, SplitDelimiter)

  'An Additional Split Introducing the Boolean
  For iIfOr = LBound(arrIfOr) To UBound(arrIfOr)
    If InStr(arrIfOr(iIfOr), "=") <> 0 Then
      If Range(Split(arrIfOr(iIfOr), "=")(0)).Value2 _
          = Range(Split(arrIfOr(iIfOr), "=")(1)).Value2 Then
        blnIfOr = True
        Exit For
      End If
    End If
  Next

  'Output
  If blnIfOr = True Then
    IFOR = ThenCell.Value2
   Else
    IFOR = ElseValue
  End If

End Function
```